# comparison [ "$var" == "value" ] always false; how can this be debugged?

Tags: string, bash, if-statement

I'm having a ton of trouble with an if statement in bash. Here's what I have:

```
if [ "$returncode"  == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]; then
    echo "Works!"
fi
```

This will not work successfully. I've verified over and over again that the variable $returncode is equal to the text specified, I'll print the two values right before this and they are definitely identical.

I've tried a couple different variations of this statement, all with no luck. I feel like a moron because this should be extremely simple! What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: show output of `declare -p returncode`

Comment: Newline at the end of the string? Try `printf %s "$returncode" | xxd`

Comment: Run `set -x` first, and give us the line printed to stderr when the comparison is run.

Comment: BTW, what's the shell? If it's POSIX sh, not bash, you need to use `=`, not `==`. (Using `=` is best-practice anyhow, since it works in both cases, whereas `==` is a shell-specific extension; see the specification for `test`, which is the command also called `[`, at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: ...and if you've "verified over and over again" using `echo`, don't -- `echo` is an extremely unreliable tool; see the caveats in its specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, and the guidance in the APPLICATION USAGE section. If your shell really is bash, use `printf '%q\n' "$returncode"` or `declare -p returncode` to emit the variable's content in an unambiguous form which will show hidden characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values truly are identical (no hidden characters), the most likely problem is that *your shell isn't actually bash*.

`/bin/sh` only promises compliance with the POSIX sh standard, and `==` isn't a valid comparison operator in POSIX test; the standard-compliant string comparison operator is `=`.

Also try eliminating a CR from the end of the line:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ NOT /bin/sh ($'...' is a non-POSIX extension)

# ...and if starting with an explicit interpreter, "bash yourscript", not "sh yourscript"

set -x # this will log each command run to stderr, allowing easy debugging

if [ "${returncode%$'\r'}" = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]; then
  echo "Works!"
fi
```

---

`${foo%val}` expands to the contents of `$foo` with any suffix consisting of `val` removed; `$'\r'` is, in bash, a constant referring to the ASCII CR character, which would be present if reading a CRLF-terminated string using standard UNIX tools (which expect LF-only newlines).

Comment: It was the carriage return! What you suggested fixed it. The == vs = wasn't an issue, both of those seem to work. I switched it to = just for the hell of it though, I guess that one is preferred.